# Etymology of using 'joint' to mean a place

Tags: etymology

What's the etymology of using 'joint' to mean a place? Like burger joint or juke joint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are referring to:

[Joint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Joint&searchmode=none):

> late 13c., "a part of a body where two bones meet and move in contact with one another," from Old French joint "joint of the body" (12c.), from Latin iunctus "united, connected, associated," past participle of iungere "join" (see jugular). Related: Joints. **Slang meaning of "place, building, establishment" (especially one where persons meet for shady activities) first recorded 1877, American English, from an earlier Anglo-Irish sense (1821), perhaps on the notion of a side-room, one "joined" to a main room. The original U.S. sense was especially of "an opium-smoking den."**

Comment: Could also derive from it being a place where you joined others...

Comment: @Oldcat - it could. But unless you give any evidence, that is mere speculation.

Comment: I never would have thought of it, but certainly "adjoining room" is a common term and 200 years ago joint came up referring to meat and perhaps this food sense, a joint as opposed to a steak had the connotation of inexpensive?